# Move types to settings.py

Tags: python, django

In one of my apps I have a file called lifecycle with types like so

```
TYPES = {
 'viaf:personal': "986a7cc9-c0c1-4720-b344-853f08c136ab",    # E21 Person
 'viaf:corporate': "3fc436d0-26e7-472c-94de-0b712b66b3f3",   # E40 Legal Body
 'viaf:geographic': "dfc95f97-f128-42ae-b54c-ee40333eae8c"    # E53 Place
}
```

I want to move them into my settings.py folder so that can be configurable from there. I am new to Django and am not sure how to go about this. What is the best way to go out doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I decided that turning these into environment variables with default values was the easiest and safest option.

Answer (score 1):

You can literally move that dictionary into your `settings.py` file and import it from whatever module you use it in:

```
from django.conf import settings

...

print(settings.TYPES['viaf:personal'])
```

Comment: So in the module I would have to add that print statement whenever I add a new type? I was hoping for more of something along the lines of adding a new type in the settings file and then having some sort of import statement in the lifecycle module that would import all the types without having to actually go into the lifecycle file and add anything. Is something like that possible?

Comment: @Taylor: I'm just using the `print` function as an example.  `settings.TYPES` is the dictionary you moved to the `settings.py` file.